# Switching to new web page with html

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the login part is clicked on the link I gave below, the page is refreshed, but I want to switch to another new white page, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score -1):

Use `target=_blank` property to open the link to new page

Answer (score -1):

Just add `target-blank`.

```
<a href="#" target="blank">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

The "href" tag is a "Hypertext Reference" so you can use this code to go to new pages or link to other .html files or even websites like Tesla.com, Amazon.com, etc. You can even link things like emails, phone numbers, Java Script, etc. Here are some examples.

```
<a href="https://www.tesla.com/">Teslas Website</a>
<a href="#" target="blank">Blank Page</a>
<a href="index.html"">Home Page</a>
<a href="tel:+1234567890"> 123 456 7890</a>
```

Hope this helped!